# Spring Roo many to many the search object references an unsaved transient instance

Tags: hibernate, annotations, many-to-many, spring-roo

I'm using spring roo generation controller..
mapping is defined as follows.

```
Class users 
    private String username;
    private String password;

 @ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.EAGER) 
   @Cascade( org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
   @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "users_id") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "roles_id") })
    private Set<Authority> roles = new HashSet<Authority>();

Class Authority 
    private String roles
    private String descricao;

@ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.EAGER ,  mappedBy = "roles") 
    @Cascade( org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE )
    private Set<Users> users = new HashSet<Users>();
```

The relationship is working, that is populating this table "Users" and Table Service "Users_roles", not the table that really Authority is expected.

The persistence of the data is going perfectly, the way it was generated by Spring roo,
Users of the controller in this way works.

```
    Users users = Users.fromJsonToUsers(json);
    users.persist();
```

The problem occurred when attempting to perform a search through the method using the relationship.

```
StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder("SELECT o FROM Users AS o WHERE LOWER(o.username) LIKE LOWER(:username)  AND LOWER(o.password) LIKE LOWER(:password)");
        queryBuilder.append(" OR");
        for (int i = 0; i < roles.size(); i++) {
            if (i > 0) queryBuilder.append(" AND");
            queryBuilder.append(" :roles_item").append(i).append(" MEMBER OF o.roles");
        }
        TypedQuery<Users> q = em.createQuery(queryBuilder.toString(), Users.class);
        q.setParameter("username", username);
        int rolesIndex = 0;
        for (Authority _authority: roles) {
            q.setParameter("roles_item" + rolesIndex++, _authority);
        }
        q.setParameter("password", password);
        return q;
```

forming a query like this:

```
(
  SELECT o
  FROM Users AS o 
  WHERE LOWER(o.username) LIKE LOWER(:username)
  AND LOWER(o.password) LIKE LOWER(:password)
  OR :roles_item0 MEMBER OF o.roles
)
```

Exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.Transi
entObjectException: **object references an unsaved transient instance - save the t
ransient instance before flushing:** br.teste.carro.domain.Authority; neste
d exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectExc
eption: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient ins
tance before flushing: br.teste.carro.domain.Authority
```

I'm suspecting that the problem is the way how I am saving but not sure.
I am grateful if someone can one of Force.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the join columns in both side of the relp, and they should be reversed on the other side:

```
Class users 
@JoinTable(name = "user_roles", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "users_id") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "roles_id") })


Class Authority 
@JoinTable(name = "user_roles", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "roles_id") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "users_id") })
```

Comment: I did as mentioned,
added the @ JoinTable on both sides, but if I have to tag mappedBy declared
I get Run-time error if you remove the tag can operate the server.
But the error still transient Object explodes in research and can not make entries .. =/
Thanks for the response....